# Results of Kernal PCA and LLE are different for different number of CPU cores provided for the run

Tags: scikit-learn, multiprocessing, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I am doing dimensionality reduction using Scikit-Learns's [KPCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.KernelPCA.html) and sometimes [LLE](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.LocallyLinearEmbedding.html) APIs.
I have dataset which has a shape of around (700X150) all numerical.
I am just trying to pass this data to one of the above mentioned APIs to reduce its features, I have written a simple python script(say run.py) for it which I can run from terminal, that also saves the data after reduction.
What issue I am facing is, I am using "taskset" command in linux terminal to assign certain number of CPUs for a particular run. I can give any number of CPUs out of how much I have on my machine, for example, the terminal command could be:
`taskset -c 1-3 python run.py` when I want to give 3 cores
or `taskset -c 1-2 python run.py` when I want to use just 2 cores.
or simply just `python run.py` when I do not want to specify any CPU.

The problem is I am getting different results in all the three cases, by different results i mean output data of there three runs are different from one another, which should not happen since I using the script, same input data, and same algorithm(either KPCA or LLE) for all the three runs, I have also kept 'n_jobs' parameter to 2 because I am at least using 2 CPUs when I am using taskset. I have also supplied a random_state. All these 3 results are totally reproducible fortunately, that means the 1st command(with 3 cores) will produce same output data on every run, similarly 2nd and 3rd command also produces same results in each of their respective runs if run multiple times.
But the question why are these output different from each other ?
Setting up the taskset in my run is important for me because I am using a multi-core machine and I need to schedule different CPUs for different tasks, sometimes I have 2, sometimes I have 3, sometimes n number of CPUs for the same task which I give them accordingly but I don't want the results to be different based on how many CPUs I gave, this is affecting my classification performance as well which is later in the pipeline.
Also, done some experiments , I don't see this behavior when I use Isomap for reducing my data. The results are same doesn't matter how many CPUs I give.
I also used "numactl" command in place of "taskset" but the behavior was same.

Surprisingly, we could also see this same behaviour when using kpca function in R language! When I use R do to the same thing. Is there anything common and fundamental here regarding KPCA that I am missing ?

Please help.
Thanks,
Pranay

Answer (score 0):

There might be something interesting in understanding exactly how the results differ.  Algorithms like LLE, PCA and k-PCA that have a matrix factorization that has a sign ambiguity (e.g. in PCA, you can negate the component vectors and negate the coefficients and have the "same" answer).  I'm not exactly what approach is being used for that matrix factorization, and what role randomization plays in that, and how it varies when it is parallelized, but it doesn't surprise me that it might be different when the computation is split across more processors, even with the same random seed.

TL;DR: If the results are different just in that some coordinates are negated, that isn't surprising.  If they are more different than that, then I don't have a good answer.